# How to stop InitializeComponent changing the form designer code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I have a override method that i'm calling in the InitializeComponent.

```
public class ComponentResourceManager2 : System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager
```

My problem is, every time that i change something in the DesignerForm the method InitializeComponent change so that the method use the system one

```
System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager();
```

Ex: I need this

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        ComponentResourceManager2 resources = new ComponentResourceManager2(typeof(Form1));
        this.directDrawViewer1 = new MyOwn.Imaging.Components.DirectDrawViewer();
        this.speedButton1 = new MyOwn.Components.SpeedButton();
        ...
```

But every time that i change something it goes again to this:

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
        this.directDrawViewer1 = new MyOwn.Imaging.Components.DirectDrawViewer();
        this.speedButton1 = new MyOwn.Components.SpeedButton();
```

How can i make my method to be the used by the InitializeComponent without being reset every time something is changed?

Comment: Dont fight the tool, designer is expected to write the initializecomponent body. You can try to create your object somewhere else, e.g. in form ctor just after initializecomponent call. Does it work?

Comment: Not really, my override method changes how the CultureInfo is selected in the resources.ApplyResourcers() so that i use the right resx file to extract the info to my labels, buttons... Therefore i need this inside the InitializeComponent. Or there is a different way to do it outside the InitializeComponent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't change the designer code, set things you are setting in InitializeComponent in the constructor of your Form after InitializeComponent() is called. Visual Studio will regenerate the designer file every time you change something in the designer